# View jumps around when clicking with 'lock to 3D cursor' enabled

Tags: 3d-view, interface, camera, 3d-cursor

Does anyone know what the intended behavior of this is?

When I set 'Lock To 3D Cursor' enabled in the 'View' tab and I middle click to pan or rotate the viewport camera it changes the distance of the camera to the 3d cursor based on the object underneath the mouse cursor.

I'd prefer if it didn't move the camera around at all when I clicked because it makes it really difficult to navigate the view. Disabling the movement would be best but I also just don't understand what it is attempting to do, knowing that would also be helpful just to understand how to use it better. If you click on nothing it behaves how I would expect, no jump in movement, and if you don't have the camera locked to the 3D cursor it behaves how I would expect as well.

Comment: When it's enabled the view will rotate around the 3D cursor.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't explain why when you tap the mouse button to rotate the camera it changes the zoom level

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to the issue I was having in the settings by unchecking 'Prefs -> Navigation -> Orbit & Pan -> Auto -> Depth'

The description says it uses depth to improve the navigation functionality but I feel like when using lock to 3d cursor it is more of a hinderance, which is a shame because it does improve the navigation when not locked.

[image: Navigation Settings]

Comment: Really useful question and answer, thumbs raised up (upvoted)!